# What is the Neutral Language setting used for?

Tags: winforms, configuration

You can find the setting accessing:

WinForms Application Properties->Application->Assembly Information->Neutral Language

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I believe it sets the [NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.neutralresourceslanguageattribute.aspx) for the assembly. From the docs:

> The `NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute`
>   informs the `ResourceManager` of the
>   language used to write the neutral
>   culture's resources for an assembly,
>   and can also inform the
>   `ResourceManager` of the assembly to use
>   (either the main assembly or a
>   satellite assembly) to retrieve
>   neutral resources using the resource
>   fallback process. When looking up
>   resources in the same culture as the
>   neutral resources language, the
>   `ResourceManager` automatically uses the
>   resources located in the main
>   assembly, instead of searching for a
>   satellite assembly with the current
>   user interface culture for the current
>   thread. This will improve lookup
>   performance for the first resource you
>   load, and can reduce your working set.

Does that help? You might also want to look at [Kim Hamilton's blog post on the topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/kimhamil/archive/2008/11/11/what-does-the-neutralresourceslanguageattribute-do.aspx).

Comment: Jon, would you happen to know the "word-breaking" behaviors associated with the "Neutral" language?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-fulltext-languages-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017   -- We are trying to use CONTAINS and CONTAINSTABLE in SQL Server against texts which have strings that contain periods (e.g. Part Code JBC.17D.19AFC7F) which we are hoping to treat as a single contiguous string, not as separate chunks.

Comment: @Tim: No, I'm afraid I don't know the details of that.

Answer (score 28):

The neutral language is used for determining which language resource that will be used when no resources are found for the language in which the application is currently run. This is called the "[resource fallback process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb6a8618.aspx)" (scroll down a bit on the page for more info).