# Working with resource.resx in windows form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, localization

I am new to resources.resx and related concept. I need some tutorial to use resource and localization for windows forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://devhood.com/tutorials/tutorial_details.aspx?tutorial_id=211) one. Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251225/proper-localization-of-a-winforms-application) stack overflow question.

Answer (score 0):

This is without a doubt your best place to start:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: @Sohnee: Thx for providing link. I need this for Window Forms right now. If you have any please provide it to me.