# Getting Multiple Font in C#

Tags: c#-2.0

I need to have malayalam and english font in my windows application.
User should enable to select the font.is there any way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Malayalam and English are languages, not fonts, so I'm guessing you're looking for localization help. Try looking at the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1251225/229858). If this isn't what you're looking for, you'll need to provide more info.