# Runtime set property from a string

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, runtime

I have a string stored in database as 'GridColumn1.Caption = "XYZ"'

Is there a way to execute this code in runtime (on windows form load) to set GridColumn1's Caption property to "XYZ" in vb.net or in c#?

I want to read it from db on form load and set the captions and texts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just store the minimum information required in the database, for example `XYZ` in a column `Caption`? Then your code is much better: `GridColumn1.Caption = dbRec.Caption`.

Comment: Hi Tim, My application is multi language so i have to change millions of objects' caption, text or tooltip property. I tried localization but not work good enough with third party elements.

Comment: What if you or others are going to change the variable name of `GridView1` to something more meningful like `GridUsers` in future? That will break your code silently (at runtime). Apart from the fact that reflection is always inefficient. Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251225/proper-localization-of-a-winforms-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can! You can use the `Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider` to compile and execute code during runtime.

More information can be found in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181668/execute-c-sharp-code-at-runtime-from-code-file).

Comment: Hi Melvin, I tried the link you posted but i guess i cannot pass my form by reference (ByRef) to the code to be compiled.

Comment: Wouldn't another option be to just store "XYZ" in the database and have your form set it's own caption by retrieving this column's content?

Comment: Form and all the control on it have to be changed. A multi language application. Translators are entering controls' captions to the database and then the application finds the right caption by user's selected language.

Comment: I suggest to either make a different table for each language (with a column for the control id, and one with the translation), or one table with different columns for each language. This will be a lot easier then having to execute code from each column. One mistake, and it won't run, crash, or the control won't be set. When everything are just `string`'s, the worst that could happen is a spelling mistake. Aside from that, Visual Studio has excellent tools for [multilingual applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj572370.aspx).