# Visual Studio 2015 Multi-Language feature makes changes not only in text

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I use two languages in Visual Basic 2015: English and German. Studio creates resource files with strings of translation text: *Ge.resx and *En.resx.

Problem: when I switch language, changing not only the text, but the location of controls, sizes, their backgrounds image. How do I prevent this? Is some property of control? I want in all languages all controls have same properties (size, location, images), except text.

Note :

> I apologize if this topic has already been and sorry for my english. I
>   could not think how to describe the problem in a few words to
>   effectively use the search.

Comment: I can only imagine that happening when the `AutoSize` property is set to `true`.

Comment: Even then, that should only affect the size.  Changing background images seems very odd.  Where are the images coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the location and size of controls is part of the .Net localization process as what may fit on a regular sized button (for example) in one language may not fit when another language is used. A word in one language may be only 5 characters long but in a different language could be 15 characters long.

When you change the form to be Localizable, a new resource file is created for each language which holds the language specific data.(You need to "Show All Files" to see them)

For example, here is a form with Danish and Afrikaans language files.

[image: Resource files]

You can edit these files if you want to remove the sizing parts of them.

[image]

This question details the steps another user took which may help you.

[Proper localization of a WinForms application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251225/proper-localization-of-a-winforms-application)